# Apache2 not able to restart in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, php

I installed Apache2 on my Ubuntu machine. At first it was working fine as I started and restarted many times in the course. But now suddenly when I tried to restart it gave me this error message:

```
[....] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob
       for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When checked `systemctl status apache2.service` it gave me the folllowing message:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-06-12 05:49:53 IST; 16s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9478 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]:  *
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: Output of config test was:
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /et
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What `journalctl -u apache2` showed:

```
Jun 12 05:47:21 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: Time has been changed
-- Subject: Time change
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The system clock has been changed to REALTIME microseconds after January 1st, 1970.
Jun 12 05:47:21 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 5h 39min 46.253658s random time.
Jun 12 05:47:21 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 1h 20min 25.260017s random time.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron sudo[9466]: yathartha : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/yathartha ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron sudo[9466]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]:  *
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: Output of config test was:
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /et
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron sudo[9466]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 12 05:51:28 yathartha-inspiron org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[1582]: ** (evolution-source-registry:1869): WARNING **: secret_servi
lines 1602-1643/1643 (END)
```

I am not able to figure out what might cause this error.

Comment: Add the output of `journalctl -u apache2` to your question and check your logfiles in `/var/log/apache2`.

Comment: Please maximise your terminal window and copy/paste the output of the above commands again. At this state we can see only the first half of every line: `Jun 11 23:12:50 yathartha-inspiron apache2[7349]: apache2: Syntax error on line???????????`?

Comment: @Spas done. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, please post the content of the mentioned lines: `Jun 12 05:49:53 yathartha-inspiron apache2[9478]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /et`

Comment: It's not printing, I tried with the full-screen mode(F11), it gave:

`apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apach`

Can't make screen more wider.

Comment: I think it's just repeating what it previously said:

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: I tried running `apache2ctl configtest`, it gave the result as:


```apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Can you please add output of `cat etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to you questions since it is already figured out that problem is caused there. Do you have `php` and `libapache2-mod-php` installed?

Comment: As the output says, there are a sybtax error on line 140 in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`and in line 2 of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load`. Please update your question with those two files.

Answer (score 0):

As the message `Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server` suggested your mod_php might have be broken/missing/accidentally removed/etc. Try run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libapache2-mod-php7.0` to reinstall the package and then restart apache again.